# webpack - option to change the internal id under which `__webpack_require__` stores modules per chunk

Tags: javascript, webpack

When webpack bundles a module inside a chunk it will store it internally like so:

```
/***/ 88:
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
```

and reference it as:

```
var _common = __webpack_require__(88);
var _common2 = _interopRequireDefault(_common);
```

If the same module is re-used in multiple chunks, webpack will give it the same module id. This is intentional so that CommonChunksPlugin can be used to extract them to an additional chunk and make the lazy loaded chunks smaller yet.

Is there a possibility to make the IDs unique per chunk though? I do not want to be able to make the "88" be "188" in all the chunks (which is what https://github.com/gogoair/custom-module-ids-webpack-plugin does, or what can be done manually by NamedChunksPlugin), I want one of the chunk to have a module as "88" and another chunk to have the same module internally as "188" (for example).

Comment: not possible because you would be touching on internals, things could get lost inside and break everything

Comment: It definitely should be possible, because you can just as well do this manually by editing the file. If you think this is imposible, please provide evidence.